# How to get the URL of an image on a web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension that would require me to save an image using the right click context. How can I replicate the "Copy image address" in Chrome using JavaScript? I just need to get the URL of the image file.

Comment: It's really not clear what exactly you want to do and what exactly is the problem, which is why we have now three answers that are probably totally irrelevant. Please elaborate. For example, describe how the user's workflow will look like. So far it sounds like you need chrome.contextMenus API in a background script and a content script with 'contextmenu' event listener.

Comment: The current way the "save image as" option works in Chrome (or any browser), particularly the file naming. I don't like it. I want to replace it with my own naming scheme (already have the idea) to better organize them. D-h-e's answer is on the right track. It gets the URL, but can't seem to replicate that in the extension. All I need is the image src URL when I right click an image, so I can use the chrome.downloads API.

Comment: Without more details I'd say you don't need a content script at all so that answer still seems inapplicable. The thing is, to show a context menu item for your extension you need chrome.contextMenus API so you can handle everything in its onClicked listener as shown in the documentation and demo extensions. Alternatively chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename might be useful here.

Comment: I already have the contextMenu API set up

Comment: In that case you already can read the image URL in onClicked listener so it's again unclear what exactly is the problem here.

Comment: Just in case, the documentation is [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked) and you can probably use `info.srcUrl`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would help:

```
window.location.origin + document.getElementById({imgId}).getAttribute('src');
```

Working example on google main page:

```
window.location.origin + document.getElementById('hplogo').getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: The first code. How can i make it work any website instead of a specific one? Every site has their own img id.

Comment: if you want just for a specific image then u need to use a specific slector, but if you want to take the path for all images on a specific page then something like this would work:
 `var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
imgs.forEach((img) => {
 let path = window.location.origin + img.getAttribute('src'); 
 console.log(path);
});`

Answer (score 0):

If you want select all images, you have to select all images for example with `document.getElementsByTagName('img')`

The result of the selection is a HTMLCollection which you can convert to an array.
Then you loop through all images and add the right click event (contextmenu) to all images.

If you right click on an image the `getURL` function gives you the path (`this.src`)

```js
const allImgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

function getURL(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.src);
}

Array.from(allImgs).forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener('contextmenu', getURL);
})
```

```html
right click on images
<br>
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0adefd53a9e8790b181785c11f458615?s=48&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1">
<br>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj5lM.png?s=32&amp;g=1">
```